# How do I solve a ModuleNotFound error: No module named 'stuff' in VSCode Python 3.10.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

I created a module named stuff, and in stuff folder, I created these files, [visual studio code preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQYZu.png)

`__init__.py`, and  `accum.py`

in `accum.py` I have

```py
class Accumulator:

    def __init__(self):
        self._count = 0
    
    @property
    def count(self):
        return self._count
        
    def add(self, more=1):
        self._count += more
```

I created a new folder `test`, and in the `test` folder I created a file `test_accum.py`

in `test_accum.py` file I have

```py
import pytest

from stuff.accum import Accumulator
```

when I run the Python file it returns:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'stuff'
```

Comment: You have to put an  `__init__.py` file in the root folder to make it a package.

Comment: Because **stuff** is on the same level as **test**, and the **stuff** module is not "installed" per se, Python won't find it when **test_accum.py** is run. You can help it by adding the path to `sys.path` in your test code before importing `stuff`: `sys.path.append('..')` (will need to `import sys` first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to run the test module, it fails because it is not in the path like @tromgy explained. However, to run tests you don't need the init files or mess with `sys.path`.

With pytest, you are not supposed to run the test module itself to run tests, but instead run pytest from command line with `python -m pytest tests`. Just make sure you are running from your project folder i.e. "tau-intro-to-pytest". If you want to run a specific test function, you can [specify that from the command line](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html#specifying-tests-selecting-tests) wtih `python -m pytest tests/test_mod.py::test_func`, but there are good VS Code extensions to do that without writing lengthy command line calls. The python [extension has a tests explorer](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing) included in it, but I like the UI of [Python Test Explorer for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter) better.